# JS regex syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do a regex pattren in JavaScript that will allow a string only with numbers and this signs: ()+ and a space. In a length of 5-16 chars.

Please Note: the order of the chars in the string is not important.

What is the right pattren for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
/^[0-9 ()+]{5,16}$/
```

It's quite easy to construct it by yourself. ) 
First, as you impose strict limits, you should check the whole string, so regex should be wrapped into `/^...$/`.

Second, if you only need some specific characters, you should use character class: write all them down into [...] form. In your case you can shortcut: replace `/^[0123456789 ()+]$/` with just `/^[0-9 ()+]$/`.

Finally, state some quantitative limits with {$min, $max} form: in your case that would be `{5,16}`. Mix this into what you got so far - and voila! You solved the task. )

Answer (score 1):

```
if( myText.match(/\A[0-9 ()+]{5,16}\Z/) ) {
    // Yay!
}
```

While it was correctly pointed out that I was missing anchor characters, using ^$ will only match the *line* of a string, therefor, "823479898237\n328742987" will match despite being too long.

Comment: This is also going to match a string like `stuff123( )443morestuff`  You need to anchor it `^$`

Comment: \A and \Z are not supported in JavaScript, and ^/$ only match the line borders instead of string ones if you explicitly state that you need multiline mode (with /m modifier).